# What kind of events we can have in chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

Right now, the only periodic event we have in chat is a "recommendation chat", and there are no non-periodic events. Keeping in mind that we want the chat to (among other things) have discussions that cannot take place in the Q&A format, what other kind of events can we have on the chat?

Answer (score 4):

We could do movie/TV show viewing parties.  Everyone loads up the same movie or show on Blu/DVD/Netflix, and we chat while watching.  This would have the extra benefit of driving more questions to the site as well.

Comment: Don't know about this one. I usually like to watch things within a few weeks of release.

Comment: I figure we'd be rewatching classics and/or really bad movies.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly would be fun to discuss a new popular book a few days after it came out. For instance, the day after something like a Harry Potter book comes out, or maybe after the season finale of any popular sci-fi series. Those would be non-periodic.

Periodic could including stuff like a monthly Star Gate/ Star Wars/ Harry Potter/ Star Gate chat (Each their own, of course), an off the beaten track chat for non-popular series, perhaps rotating each chat over a series or just having it be a free for all, a semi-reoccurring sci-fi fandom chat which discusses stuff like conventions and other ancillary stuff. Maybe even a genre identification chat, but these would be pretty sparse, maybe once every few months.

Basically, anything off topic to the FAQ, but still interesting, would be good as well.

So, just to put it in a nice, neat list, I'm proposing the following:

Once a week of the 4 largest sci-fi TV/movie franchise series, rotating each week which one it is.

- Star Trek
- Star Wars
- Dr. Who
- Star Gate

Once a month for each of these, at the same time and a week or so apart.

- Fandom/ state of the genre chat
- Scifi.SE meta discussion (On topic, moderation, what should we do to promote it, etc)
- Genre classification chat
- Recommendation's chat

Once a month chats for:

- Harry Potter
- Discworld
- LOTR
- Opened to any books

Comment: I like these ideas. Let's update this answer with times.

Comment: The trick is to assign times of the week for each one. Hmmm... If we want week days, I suppose it's Tuesday, Wednesday, and Thursday.

Comment: Our main problem with the chat events is the lack of participation. I don't think such specialized events would be useful. I would prefer to have more frequent events and just chat about whatever the participants have in mind.

Comment: I think that specialized chats could bring in a larger audience actually, and might be more successful. Of course, getting them started is always the issue. But still, maybe we could just have one be TV, one books, one movies, and one open bag day, including all of the things in the second set of recommendations. That might be a better way to start.

Answer (score 1):

After some thought, I'm going to make a different suggestion, one that I hope will be more acceptable.

We should have only 1 chat a week, at least to start out with. The topic should rotate among 4 discussions, which are:

1. TV Series
2. Movies
3. Books (I suppose comics could be included in here)
4. Recommendations, genre classification, fandom, etc.

I think once a week is just about right, so as to not be too crazy, but still be obtainable. Perhaps we'll spend some weeks focusing on key series, but those will be less frequent. If these chats become more popular, we can work towards the suggestions in my previous post.

Comment: If we only have one a week, can it alternate day/time?  Although I'm the only one that's suggested a time for the proposed alternate recommendation date, it does seem possible that there would be others that are unable to make the current date/time and don't know about the meta question.

Comment: That would be easy enough to do. Hmmm.